Angular 17 - In @if syntax, how to store returned value from a function in a variable and use it in the same @if block
In my case, I have following block of code that I can store the info value in the *ngIf expression block and use in the template, how to do the same with newly introduced @if syntax in Angular 17?
I couldn't find any samples/docs that can do the same using @if syntax.
<div *ngIf="getMatchingImage() as info">
  <img class="empty-cart-img" [src]="info.imageUrl" width="70%" decoding="async" loading="lazy" alt="Empty List">
  <figcaption>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </figcaption>
</div>


For the @if block, the syntax will be:
@if (<value>; as <variable>)

@if (getMatchingImage(); as info) {
  <img
    class="empty-cart-img"
    [src]="info.imageUrl"
    width="70%"
    decoding="async"
    loading="lazy"
    alt="Empty List"
  />
  <figcaption>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </figcaption>
}

Demo @ StackBlitz
Reference: Angular - @if

Got it , https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/tools/manual_api_docs/blocks/if.md#L0-L0
Thanks @Yong
